# Run script if browser width changes

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I've got a 1 page website, when a navigation button is clicked, it scrolls to the selected div.

On a browser with a width of 1006px or more, a header will show with height:60px; which is fixed to the top.

I have the following script which works perfectly fine on a browser width of more than 1006px but on i.e mobile version, i'm getting a 60px gap at the top.

This is the lines I need to edit

```
var offsetHeader = 60;
```

and

```
var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-60;
```

as you'll notice, I have 60 set which is the height of the div, I can change this to 0 which will then work perfect on a mobile version, I need to edit it so that when the browser's width changes then this will change to either 60 or 0.

Here's the full jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var offsetHeader = 60; //Add the height of the header if needed, also change line 31

        $('.scroll').click(function(){
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $('body').stop().scrollTo( $target , 800, {'axis':'y', offset: -offsetHeader});
            return false;
        });

        /**
        * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
        * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and
        * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
        */
        var aChildren = $("nav ul li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
        var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
        for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {
            var aChild = aChildren[i];
            var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
            aArray.push(ahref);
        } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
            var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
            var docHeight = $(document).height();

            for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
                var theID = aArray[i];
                var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-60; // match the number with the offsetHeader
                var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
                if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("active");
                } else {
                    $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("active");
                }
            }

            if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
                if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                    var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                    $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                    $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm thinking something like the following code but not sure how I can implement it with the script?

```
function updateContainer() {
    var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($containerWidth > 1006) {
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-60;
        var offsetHeader = 60;
    } else { 
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-0;
        var offsetHeader = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I'm just going through them now, everyone so far seems to stop the scroll from working but i'm still checking.

Answer (score 1):

I didn'r really understood the objective, but maybe this will help:

```
var cWidth;

$(window).resize(function() {
    cWidth = $(window).width();
    if (cWidth > 1006) {
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-60;
        var offsetHeader = 60;
    } else { 
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top-0;
        var offsetHeader = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank but I need the whole jQuery script implemented as it won't work if I take those lines out and do add your code above.

Comment: Because `theID` variable is local and can't be accessed from outside the for loop. Let me edit this a bit

Answer (score 0):

Use the resize event of window

```
$(window).resize(updateContainer).resize();
```

By triggering the event after declaring the handler it will also fire on page load